# Kafka Spark streaming XML parsing/processing

Tags: xml, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have few XML files & I have put those in a Kafka topic & i have created Dstream object of the Kafka topic. I am not able to proceed further as I want to parse the xml data from the topic. Please if anyone who has worked on xml processing in Spark streaming can give their inputs for me to proceed. I am stuck with this from past 2 days.

The approach which I am taking is XML files -> Kafka topic -> processing in Spark streaming -> again put it back in Kafka.

I am able to put data back into Kafka topic but not able to process or do anything with the data from the topic in spark streaming.

Comment: could you add your code and be specific in what the problem is and  what error(s) or exceptions are you getting?

Comment: @Harsha am running into a same issue while reading the messages from kafka am getting the messages as each tag as a message. could you please let me know how did you solve the issue.

Comment: @ankush reddy use JAXB to validate the xml's with their respective schemas

Answer (score 1):

What processing are you expecting.?

if you are expecting any kind of data extraction, what you can do is, foreach message, convert them to json (xml to json is very easy) and get the jsonRDD and JsonRDD to DF is direct conversion. So, you will be able to any selection or any other operations on the data frame.

I need few more inputs from you, in order to provide exact solution

1) What you want out of the data.?
2) Is Dataframe out of the data is sufficient.?

If you are able to explain with input, that would be very helpful.

I have added a sample code to do get the dataframe out of the xml data.

```
val jsonStream = kafkaStream.transform(
      y => {
        y.filter(x => x._1 != null && x._2 != null).map(x => {
          XML.toJSONObject(x).toString(4);
        }
        )
      })


jsonStream.foreachRDD(x => {
      val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(x.sparkContext)
      if (x != null) {

        val df = sqlContext.read.json(x)
        // Your DF Operations
        }
      }
    }
)

object SQLContextSingleton {

  @transient private var instance: HiveContext = _

  def getInstance(sparkContext: SparkContext): HiveContext = {
    if (instance == null) {
      sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false");
      sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true");
      sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata","false");
      instance = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
    }
    instance
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Srini, thanks for your quick reply. The issue is resolved, it was a very complex use case, where we wanted to link 3 types of xml's using spark streaming. finally it's done. We used JAXB to validate the xml's with their respective schemas. As I said the usecase is quite complex, there is lot of coding, hence I am not sharing any piece of code which worked for me. Thank you once again.